# Make array out of specific characters in a string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

So lets say i have a string : "a = b + c - d"

I want to create a character array that will hold these expression signs(=,-,+,) and convert them to an array for example in this case the array would be 
{'=','+','-'}

example of the code:

```
   string s = "a = b + c -d"
   char[] array = s.???('=','-','+');
```

is there an easy way to this is without loops?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have a list of operators you're looking for?  Does the order in the resulting array matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use linq and do something like this:

```
char[] operators = new char[] { '=', '-', '+' };
string s = "a = b + c -d";
var opArray = s.Where(x=>operators.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

You can add all the operators you need in the `operators` array

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to select characters which are not letters or whitespace

```
var array = s.Where(c => !Char.IsLetter(c) && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray();
```

Output:

```
[ '=',  '+',  '-' ]
```

---

You can also create extension method to make code more readable and select only math operators

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static HashSet<char> mathOperators =
        new HashSet<char>(new[] { '+', '-', '=' }); // add more symbols here
    public static bool IsMathOperator(this char c) => mathOperators.Contains(c);
}
```

And usage

```
var array = s.Where(c => c.IsMathOperator()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but i may also add `!Char.IsDigit(c)`, just in case

Comment: @Pikoh maybe list of valid operators is better in that case. That depends whether OP formulas use digits and whether there is lot of valid operators :)

Comment: that why i suggested my answer, but i agree, it depends on OP formulas :)